# Regex Capture Groups on a Variably Formatted String

Tags: regex

I have a 3-field string that is delimited by commas. Sometimes the string can be composed of two fields only. I am trying to capture the first field in this string. Here are some examples of the string:

```
string: abc,xyz
string: abc,xyz,323 
regex: (.*),(.*),(.*)
```

Note: Assume none of these fields can have commas

Comment: Is there a split function in your programming language? If there is I would suggest using it instead.

Comment: I would except the 'split' function in Pig seems highly inflexible: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#TOKENIZE

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to capture the first field, couldn't you use `^([^,]*)`?

i.e. from the beginning of the string, get as many non-commas as possible

EDIT: Taking the comment into account, how about `^([^,]+),([^,]+)(?:,([^,]+))?$`?

Comment: I would still like to retain the fact that strings can be of either the comma-delimited 2/3 field string.